# Split array after Character

Tags: php

I am searching for a php function to split a array after a specific character.

In Java, we can do:

```
String.split(" ");
```

Comment: The people of SO arent your personal search agents, try putting in some effort yourself. PHP has a decent manual where all functions are documented, try looking there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the `explode()` function to split on a character and return an array of strings.

For regular expressions you can use `preg_split()`

References: 
http://be.php.net/manual/en/function.explode.php
http://be.php.net/manual/en/function.preg-split.php